# IOS Calabash Ruby Get the Simulator Setting details

Tags: ruby, automation, calabash

I am new to the Calabash and Ruby.
While automating the test cases I need the status of the Location Servies weather it is On or Off. I searched a lot about this and so far no luck at all.

Please let me know if this can be done

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this works or not but have you tried setting location? I am just guessing here but perhaps that returns differently if location service is off compared to on.

Comment: You can use this method `set_location place:'Tower of London'` , if it shows error your Location Service may be off. It is indirect method but it will help you. @Anjil